# WPF Custom Control Design Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, custom-controls

My application runs fine, the error in visual studio is just driving me crazy.  The actual error is:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\emailTemplates'.

My program starts up, and populates a combo box with all of the .msg files in a directory relative to the application.  like i said, it compiles and runs fine.  I have tried rebuilding, cleaning, etc.  nothing works.  cleaning seems to fix it, until I build it again. What is going on??

[image]

Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="abfsEmailGenerator.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:custom ="clr-namespace:abfsEmailGenerator"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="600">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander x:Name="emailSelectExpander" Header="Select Email" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="592">
        <custom:HtmlViewer></custom:HtmlViewer>
    </Expander>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

HtmlViewer:

```
<UserControl x:Class="abfsEmailGenerator.HtmlViewer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="28*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="243*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Margin="3" Grid.Row="0">CC:</Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="ccText" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Label Margin="3" Grid.Row="1">Subject:</Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="subjectText" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <WebBrowser Margin="3,3,3,33"  x:Name="bodyBrowser" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="500" Grid.RowSpan="2"></WebBrowser>
    <ComboBox x:Name="emailSelector" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" DropDownClosed="emailSelector_DropDownClosed"/>
</Grid>
```

HtmlViewer Code:

```
namespace abfsEmailGenerator
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for HtmlViewer.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class HtmlViewer : UserControl
{
    outlook.Application oApp = new outlook.Application();       
    private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>> emailDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

    public HtmlViewer()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        populateCb();



    }


    private void populateCb()
    {
        string emailFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/emailTemplates";
        emailDict.Clear();
        emailSelector.ItemsSource = null;
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(emailFolder, "*.msg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you completely quit visual studio and the problem happens again?  i get "phantom" errors all the time that don't go away until all instances of visual studio are shut down...

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.  It usually works, but not this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot create instance of 'HTMLViewer'.

*That suggests that initialization may be the culprit.*

In design mode you don't want the control trying to do work other than setting up the basic look and feel of the control.

To keep operational activities to a minimum, which may create null instance failures, its best to segregate code which has a high possibility of failure as such:

```
 public HtmlViewer()
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) // If NOT in design mode...do work.
        populateCb();  
 }
```

Depending on how the dependency properties are setup, they may not be handling null properly and causing issues; if so the above code could apply.

Comment: when I try to use `System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty` the editor throws a error saying that the '!' operator cannot be applied to an operand of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'.  Am I accessing the wrong property?

Comment: @MichaelBillingham updated, sorry for the wrong call. See update